# CONCATENATE a string with an ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I have the following string in column H and I.

```
H2="http://"
I2="aaa"
H3="http://"
I3="bbb"
```

I want to have a auto-generated J column, which results like:

```
J2="http://aaa"
J3="http://bbb"
```

So I put the following formula in J1:

```
= ARRAYFORMULA (IF(ROW(J:J)=1;"formulaTest";CONCATENATE(H:H1, I:I1 ) ))
```

But the result I got is:

```
J2="http://http://aaabbb"
J3="http://http://aaabbb"
```

What is going wrong with my formula?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((IF(ROW(J:J)=1,"formulaTest",H1:H & I1:I)))
```

Comment: Great! It finally works now!.
Though I still don't know why I can not use "CONCATENATE", instead I need to use "&" in this formula.

Comment: @srjohnhuang With the `CONCATNATE`, the complete column range is fed to the `ARRAYFORMULA`. Using the ampersand, only the single entries are fed, giving you the desired result.

Comment: The reason you can use & but not concatenate() is that concatenate can take a range whereas & can only join specific discreet values.

Answer (score 14):

In Google Sheets, the simplest solution is to just use CONCAT instead of CONCATENATE.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(CONCAT(H1:H,I1:I))
```

CONCAT will return only two values and can be used in this manner for an array formula. You cannot use CONCATENATE because (as mentioned by others) it will return the whole array.

Comment: Or even shorter, `=arrayformula(H1:H & I1:I)`

Answer (score 2):

#### Formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(IF(V2:V="","",(CONCAT(CONCAT(V2:V," - "),W2:W)))))
```

#### Functions

1. ARRAYFORMULA -   Enables applying the formula to an entire column
2. UNIQUE -   Removes duplicates from the results
3. IF: Tests if column V is empty using `V2:V=""`

   1. 'value_if_true' is an empty string `""`
   2. 'value_if_false' is two nested CONCAT functions
      `CONCAT(CONCAT(V2:V; " - "); W2:W)`

      1. Nested one joins column V with `" - "`
      2. Outer one joins nested one with column W
         return nothing, otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for concating multiple columns with a glue string:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A) ,, IFERROR(H2:H & "-" & I2:I ,'Attention!')))
```

the `IF(ISBLANK(A2:A)` part is added so that `ARRAYFORMULA` does not perform on empty rows of the sheet.