# How do I prepend a string to a column of cells in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

I imagine this is laughably simple but I just don't know what to do. I have a column (A) of cells with strings in them and I want to simply prepend each string in every cell with a web address:

```
A
--------
1| /foo/bar/
2| /foo/foo/
3| /foo/baz/
...
```

I want:

```
A
--------
1| http://foo.com/foo/bar/
2| http://foo.com/foo/foo/
3| http://foo.com/foo/baz/
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [CONCATENATE a string with an ArrayFormula](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54645/concatenate-a-string-with-an-arrayformula)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do that with a formula, so that e.g. column `B` will display the URL:

```
="http://foo.com" & A1
```

<sup>(the `&` is the string concatenation operator in Google Spreadsheets)</sup>

Put this formula in `B1`, and copy-paste it to other cells in the `B` column.

Answer (score 6):

For completeness, use this formula to add in `B1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("http://foo.com" & A1:A)
```

See similar post here on Web applications: [CONCATENATE a string with an ArrayFormula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/54645/29140)

Answer (score 5):

You can put this in another cell: `="http://foo.com" & A1`

This will result in:

```
  A            | B
----------------------------------------
1| /foo/bar/   | http://foo.com/foo/bar/
2| /foo/foo/   | http://foo.com/foo/foo/
3| /foo/baz/   | http://foo.com/foo/baz/
```

Or, if you prefer, you can use the [CONCATENATE](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3094123) function:

```
=CONCATENATE("http://foo.com",A1)
```

([CONCAT](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093592) is the same, but it only concatenates two values, while CONCATENATE lets you do multiple, even in ranges.)

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using the search and replace feature in Google Sheets with regular expression and specified range.

In the search and replace dialog use these values

```
Find: ^/(.+) 
Replace: http://$1
```

Make sure you select the option "Search using regular expression"
You can specify a cell range so you do not accidently replace values unintentionally.

The expression in the find field of `^/(.+)` means the following:

- The `^/` indicates that the value being searched must start with `/`
- The `()` defines a capturing group so everything matched by the pattern inside the capture group will be able to be used in the replace field with `$1`
- The `.` means match any character.
- The `+` means match 1 or more.
- The combination of `.+` means match 1 or more of any character.

The expression in the replace field of `http://$1` means the following:

- The `http://` is just text
- The `$1` means first capture group
- Together the `http://$1` means replace the cell with the text `http://` plus whatever was matched in the first capture group.

**Before Replace**

[image: Before Replace]

**After Replace**

[image: After Replace]