# How to add a string to the start and end of a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have lots of cells that contain unique text.

I'd like to add a `<p>` to the start of the cell and a `</p>` to the end of the string in the cell.

Turning this:
`Here is some text I've written. It's different in each cell.`
into this:
`<p>Here is some text I've written. It's different in each cell.</p>`

I've tried `=CONCATENATE("<p>",A1)` but can't find a way to add something to the end of the cell as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add another parameter to your `CONCATENATE`:

```
=CONCATENATE("<p>", A1, "</p>")
```

(you might have to use `;` instead of `,` depending on your locale)
See [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094123)

This can be shortened to

```
="<p>" & A1 & "</p>"
```

since `&` is the [string concatenation operator](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57214/21583).